# Javascript/JQuery. Cache xml file locally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using `$.ajax({..})` I receive the contents of an XML file from the server. So I don't have to request this file every time the page loads, I would like, if possible, to cache this content locally, save it in a file on the disk. But cache it in such a way that it will be available even the next day, after a restart. The XML file content updates daily so no need to resend the file so often.

Is it possible? If so, how can i achieve this? Could you offer a link or some sample code please? I've searched for something good which I can understand, but i was not successful.

Comment: You can use "cache:true" option in your ajax request.

Comment: and how long will that cache it? Will it get deleted on browser restart or ... i don't know?

Comment: Yes it will be new when browser restarts.

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't a way to make it last a couple of hours or so ?

Comment: I was just about to, but i wanted to know if there was a way to make it stay even after browser restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need this

http://brian.io/lawnchair/

Comment: I looked a bit over the documentation for this and was not able to see and understand if the cache persisted on browser restart, or PC restart. Do you, by any chance, know if it does or not?

Comment: Yes it is persistent even is somebody closes the app or browser

Comment: hei Ashirvad Singh, why the hell is the function "exists" return an object, and how the hell do i get a boolean value from it?

Answer (score 1):

By default, a browser will typically cache responses for you depending on how the server sets the file headers. If you need persistance beyond that, you can use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) and possibly cookies for legacy support (although there are very real size limits whet it comes to storage).

Using local storage is simple enough. You can also bring an expiry timestamp with that to let the client know when it’s time to renew the cache.

A barebone example:

```
var mydata = { foo: 'bar' };
var cache = {
    data: mydata,
    expires: new Date().getTime()
}

sessionStorage.setItem("cache", JSON.stringify(cache));
```

And to grab the data:

```
var cache = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem("cache") );
if ( cache.expires + day < new Date().getTime() ) {
    // get a fresh copy
} else {
    var mydata = cache.data;
}
```

There are numerous local cache abstractions you can use instead if you are more comfortable with a higher level of API.

Comment: I found that "DOM Storage is supported in the following browsers- FF3.5+, Chrome4+, Safari4+, Opera10.5+, and IE8+". Hmm, i'm guessing this won't work for the Android Browser for mobile devices ...

Comment: I believe Android’s default browser is WebKit based and should support local storage. iOS is Safari and it should definitely support it.